# What is a better way to present sign up / login form?

Tags: layout, signup-signon, homepage

It has become quite common and dare I say annoying these days to see websites and mobile apps prominently highlighting the 'sign up' for new user fields but at the same time why do they make 'Login' for existing users so hard to find?

I understand that these companies want to get more users onboard, but it just makes a poor experience for existing users, case in point - try to find the login button in this screenshot taken from https://www.pinterest.com home screen, it took me a while to locate it.

[image]

So the question is, how would you make sign-on for existing users better without creating a barrier for new users to sign-up?

Comment: I agree with Sepas about the Google and FB account signup/login. This might tie up to the organization's business/marketing needs and goals as well. Taking this to the account may have an impact on how the designer display the sign-in button on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To some extents and according to the context that you described you're right. Users have to try hard to find the login button. But if you look at it based on the common practice that nowadays almost everyone use their Google or Facebook account to signup/login the situation that you mentioned above is not the most catastrophic. Of course I'm not suggesting that the login button should be this small and out of focus.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems that you describe.

**1. Speed for which a new user enters.**
For such things, fast login via Google, Facebook ... or through other popular platforms has long been used.
This speeds up a login and does not require the user to remember passwords.

Another option is the password master. It is available on all devices and can be built-in (for example, in a browser) or local (for example, 1 password). With it, you can also log into different accounts in a matter of seconds.

**2. Overlay login for a new user and already registered.**
Unfortunately, companies cannot completely separate the flow for the entry of new users and existing ones.
Sometimes they do it at some point in your flow. For example, in Pinterest this happens as soon as you open the page, on Instagram after scrolling the feed, in site builders when you create a new project...
Now this problem can only be solved by thinking through the login pattern and working out the user flow.

I hope I was able to answer your question.